# Род иноязычных аббревиатур

Tags: заимствования, аббревиатуры, род

Всегда ли род иноязычной непереводной аббревиатуры можно определить по опорному слову? Корректно ли определен род следующих ниже аббревиатур?

- НАТО (*Организация* Североатлантического договора) – ж. р.
- ЮНЕСКО (*Организация* Объединенных Наций по вопросам образования, науки и культуры) – ж. р.
- ХАМАС («Исламское *движение* сопротивления») – ср. р.
- ФИПРЕССИ (Международная *федерация* кинопрессы) – ж. р.
- ЦЕРН (Европейская *организация* по ядерным исследованиям) – ж. р.
- УЕФА (*Союз* европейских футбольных ассоциаций) – м. р.
- ФИАС (Международная *федерация* самбо) – ж. р.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не всегда. Обычно определяют по опорному слову в расшифровке  или же по **родовому слову**:МГУ (университет — м.р.) принял новых студентов, СНГ (содружество — с.р.) выступило с инициативой, ЮНЕСКО (организация — ж.р.) объявила 2011 год годом лесов.

Род звуковой инициальной аббревиатуры (читаемой «по слогам») зависит не только от рода опорного слова, но и от внешнего фонетического облика аббревиатуры, точнее – от ее концовки. Так, если аббревиатура оканчивается на согласный, то она может согласовываться по мужскому роду, несмотря на принадлежность опорного слова к женскому или среднему роду. Причем в некоторых случаях согласование по мужскому роду является единственно возможным.

Например, только мужского рода слова вуз (хотя заведение), МИД (хотя министерство), загс (хотя запись). В некоторых случаях наблюдаются колебания: например, МКАД – мужского рода в разговорной речи, женского рода в стилистически нейтральных контекстах.

В некоторых случаях согласование по мужскому роду невозможно: ГЭС, ТЭЦ – существительные только женского рода. О родовой принадлежности таких аббревиатур следует справляться в словарях.

Род иноязычной аббревиатуры определяется по опорному слову в русской расшифровке:  ФИФА (федерация) приняла решение; ЦЕРН (центр) провел исследования.

Однако в некоторых случаях на родовую принадлежность может оказывать влияние внешний фонетический облик слова. Например, аббревиатура **НАТО используется как существительное мужского рода** (в результате влияния сочетания со словами альянс, блок, договор), **женского рода** (по опорному слову организация) и **среднего рода** (по фонетическому облику, ср. с другими словами на -О: пальто, метро, кино).

Испытывает **колебания** в роде аббревиатура ЮНЕСКО (фонетический облик подсказывает **средний** род, а опорное слово организация – **женский**).Но чаще используется всё же женский род.

Ср., муж.,ХАМАС («Исламское движение сопротивления») – ср. р. и муж.:ХАМАС предложил

ФИПРЕССИ –ж. (Международная федерация кинопрессы) – ж. р.

ЦЕРН – Европейский **центр** ядерных исследований(родовое слово)- мужск.(первая делегация из СССР появилась в ЦЕРНе в 1959 году.)

УЕФА (Союз европейских футбольных ассоциаций) – м. р.

ФИАС (Международная федерация самбо) – ж. р.

Answer (score 0):

Род иноязычной аббревиатуры определяется по опорному слову в русской расшифровке:  ФИФА (федерация) приняла решение; ЦЕРН (центр) провел исследования. Однако в некоторых случаях на родовую принадлежность может оказывать влияние внешний фонетический облик слова. Например, аббревиатура **НАТО используется как существительное мужского рода (в результате влияния сочетания со словами альянс, блок, договор), женского рода (по опорному слову организация) и среднего рода (по фонетическому облику, ср. с другими словами на -О: пальто, метро, кино).** Испытывает колебания в роде аббревиатура ЮНЕСКО (фонетический облик подсказывает средний род, а опорное слово организация – женский).

НАТО (Организация Североатлантического договора) – **м., ж. и ср.**

ЮНЕСКО (Организация Объединенных Наций по вопросам образования, науки и культуры) – **ж. р. с.р**

ХАМАС («Исламское движение сопротивления») – **ср. р.**

ФИПРЕССИ (Международная федерация кинопрессы) – **ж. р.**

ЦЕРН (Европейская организация по ядерным исследованиям) – **м. р.   (опорное слово центр)**

УЕФА (Союз европейских футбольных ассоциаций) – **м. р.**

ФИАС (Международная федерация самбо) – **ж. р.**

Answer (score 0):

Во всех доступный мне **живых** источниках ХАМАС - мужского рода.

Нацкорпус:

При этом многие ставят под сомнение эффективность операции: ХАМАС уже **ответил** на одностороннее перемирие Израиля новыми обстрелами его территории. [Илья Кричевский, Виктор Дятликович. Война. Громят врага еврейские танкисты // «Русский репортер», № 1-2 (080-081), 22-29 января 2009, 2009]

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%90%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A1):

ХАМАС **признан** террористической организацией Израилем, Канадой, США и Японией, а также запрещён в Иордании и Египте[3]. В Австралии и Великобритании террористическим признают только военное крыло ХАМАС. В декабре 2014 года Европейский суд общей юрисдикции предписал исключить ХАМАС из списка террористических организаций Европейского союза, оставив в силе список ЕС от 22.07.2014, включающий ХАМАС. 27 марта 2015 года ЕС продлил признание ХАМАС террористической организацией на период рассмотрения поданной им апелляции на решение суда

[Лента](https://lenta.ru/lib/14160709/).ру:

ХАМАС резко **выступил** против прекращения огня